# How to validate user input for month entry in date?

Tags: c++, date, validation, user-input

I am writing a program to validate user input for date entry with format 01 Jan 1900. I have written code to validate the leap year and day limit for each month but I have been unable to validate the text entry for each month.

This is the part of the code that is not working yet; the validation of the string entry such that any user input apart from Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr.......Dec will throw the error "Wrong entry, please enter valid date"

```
  if (( month != "Jan" || month != "Feb" || month != "Mar" || month != "Apr" 
     || month != "May" || month != "Jun" || month != "Jul" || month != "Aug" 
     || month != "Sep" || month != "Oct" || month != "Nov" || month != "Dec"))    
  {
      std::cout << "Wrong entry, please enter valid date." << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << day << " " << month << " " << year;
  }
```

Comment: Can u post full code , so we can see how u init the month varable and help u !

Answer (score 6):

You're checking if the month is not "Jan" OR not "Feb" OR etc. Since the month can't be all possible months at once, your `if` condition will always be true.

Replace the `||` in your condition with `&&`, and it will work correctly.